# How can i start Apache Cassandra as a service?

Tags: cassandra

I have Apache Cassandra 2.1.0 on Amazon instance with Ubuntu 14.Is it possible to start Apache Cassandra as a service?

Comment: Did you install using the debian package or a tarball ?

Comment: I installed   apache-cassandra-2.1.0-bin.tar.gz

Comment: That's the problem. The tarball install does not ship with demonizing script. You might have to write your own. you can start here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html

Answer (score 9):

I don't have reputation to comment, but please do NOT use these start scripts suggested by others right out of the box!

The following issues are present in them:

- The server is started as root user, very bad!
- The error checking is flawed, the test for $? after a sleep is sure to lead 0
- A few more issues that stem from the use of root as creator of the PID file

A corrected script for Debian below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Cassandra database
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             cassandra
# Required-Start:       $remote_fs $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Apache Cassandra database server
# Description:          Apache Cassandra database server
### END INIT INFO

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

CASSANDRA_HOME=/home/db/packages/apache-cassandra
CASSANDRA_BIN=$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/cassandra
CASSANDRA_NODETOOL=$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/nodetool
CASSANDRA_LOG=$CASSANDRA_HOME/logs/cassandra.log
CASSANDRA_PID=/var/run/cassandra.pid
CASSANDRA_LOCK=/var/lock/subsys/cassandra
PROGRAM="cassandra"
USER=db

if [ ! -f $CASSANDRA_BIN ]; then
  echo "File not found: $CASSANDRA_BIN"
  exit 1
fi

RETVAL=0

start() {
  log_action_begin_msg "Starting $PROGRAM"
  if [ -f $CASSANDRA_PID ] && checkpid `cat $CASSANDRA_PID`; then
    echo "Cassandra is already running."
    exit 0
  fi
  log_action_msg "Executing command as user $USER"
  TMPFILE=/tmp/cassandra.$RANDOM
  su --login $USER --command "$CASSANDRA_BIN -p $TMPFILE" >> $CASSANDRA_LOG 2>&1
  RETVAL=$?
  cat $TMPFILE > $CASSANDRA_PID
  rm $TMPFILE
  sleep 10
  if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then
    touch $CASSANDRA_LOCK
    log_action_end_msg $RETVAL
  else
    log_failure_msg "returned $RETVAL on startup"
  fi
  return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
  log_action_begin_msg "Stopping $PROGRAM: "
  if [ ! -f $CASSANDRA_PID ]; then
    log_action_msg "Cassandra is already stopped."
    exit 0
  fi
  $CASSANDRA_NODETOOL disablegossip
  $CASSANDRA_NODETOOL disablethrift
  $CASSANDRA_NODETOOL drain
  if kill `cat $CASSANDRA_PID`; then
    RETVAL=0
    rm -f $CASSANDRA_LOCK
    log_action_end_msg 0
  else
    RETVAL=1
    log_failure_msg "can't kill PID $CASSANDRA_PID"
  fi
  return $RETVAL
}

status_fn() {
  if [ -f $CASSANDRA_PID ] && checkpid `cat $CASSANDRA_PID`; then
    echo "Cassandra is running."
    exit 0
  else
    echo "Cassandra is stopped."
    exit 1
  fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  status)
    status_fn
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Usage: $PROGRAM {start|stop|restart|status}"
    RETVAL=3
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: I would be very careful about this line:

$CASSANDRA_NODETOOL decommission

That will take your node out of the cluster every time you issue a stop. I can't think of a good time to do that without explicitly doing a decommission separately.

Comment: @PatrickMcFadin very good point. I improved my startup script to disable gossip, thrift and then drain which seems to be the recommended way. Post adjusted.

Comment: @Matt, I am converting your script to run on rhel but I am afraid that I may mess it up. Do you have this script for rhel?

Comment: @DavidF, unfortunately I don't have it directly for RHEL yet, but I think the only bits that may be different is the messaging and a few tiny changes here and there - logic should be the same. I would just give it a try and see what doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes you can**, If you are using debian package then automatically it will register as a service. But you are using tar, so you need to follow the steps given in the below link.

**http://jansipke.nl/centos-cassandra-init-start-stop-script/**

There is no matter it is debian or cent family when you are using tarball.

Comment: I went through the script.I checked with my Cassandra.I could not find cassandra.log in log directory,  and also cassandra.pid in /var/run

Comment: Did you followed all the steps described in the link? Make sure that you are running in super user(root) and make sure the cassandra folder has executable permissions(chmod -R 777 <cassandraFolderName>).

Comment: Simple way to track is, add echo statement. Then you can find easily where it is breaking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the startup script cassandra and put that script into the ***/etc/init.d/***.

You can refer to the [link](http://techpost360.blogspot.in/2015/07/start-apache-cassandra-as-service-on.html)

```html
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 99 01
# description: Cassandra

. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

CASSANDRA_HOME=/opt/apache-cassandra-0.7.4
CASSANDRA_BIN=$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/cassandra
CASSANDRA_NODETOOL=$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/nodetool
CASSANDRA_LOG=$CASSANDRA_HOME/log/cassandra.log
CASSANDRA_PID=/var/run/cassandra.pid
CASSANDRA_LOCK=/var/lock/subsys/cassandra
PROGRAM="cassandra"

if [ ! -f $CASSANDRA_BIN ]; then
  echo "File not found: $CASSANDRA_BIN"
  exit 1
fi

RETVAL=0

start() {
  if [ -f $CASSANDRA_PID ] && checkpid `cat $CASSANDRA_PID`; then
    echo "Cassandra is already running."
    exit 0
  fi
  echo -n $"Starting $PROGRAM: "
  daemon $CASSANDRA_BIN -p $CASSANDRA_PID >> $CASSANDRA_LOG 2>&1
  usleep 500000
  RETVAL=$?
  if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then
    touch $CASSANDRA_LOCK
    echo_success
  else
    echo_failure
  fi
  echo
  return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
  if [ ! -f $CASSANDRA_PID ]; then
    echo "Cassandra is already stopped."
    exit 0
  fi
  echo -n $"Stopping $PROGRAM: "
  $CASSANDRA_NODETOOL -h 127.0.0.1 decommission
  if kill `cat $CASSANDRA_PID`; then
    RETVAL=0
    rm -f $CASSANDRA_LOCK
    echo_success
  else
    RETVAL=1
    echo_failure
  fi
  echo
  [ $RETVAL = 0 ]
}

status_fn() {
  if [ -f $CASSANDRA_PID ] && checkpid `cat $CASSANDRA_PID`; then
    echo "Cassandra is running."
    exit 0
  else
    echo "Cassandra is stopped."
    exit 1
  fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  status)
    status_fn
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Usage: $PROGRAM {start|stop|restart|status}"
    RETVAL=3
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

after that you can use the following commands to start and stop the cassandra as a serivce.

- Start : - $service cassandra start
- Stop : - $service cassandra stop